# Trying to set the state to a value from using a GET in reactjs,

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The value is undefined when i `console.log` it. Trying to fetch data based on the state of a value that isn't `null`, the **dashboardID** value should be 1, but its `undefined`, why?

```
getDashboardID = _ => {
    fetch(`http://ca-fpscfb2:4000/dashboardID?name=${this.state.Dashboard}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => { 
      this.setState({ dashboardID: res.dashboardID }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.dashboardID)
      })
     })


} 

handleChangeDashboard = (Dashboard) => {
    this.setState({ Dashboard: Dashboard.value });
    this.getDashboardID();

  }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `this.setState` is async and your response is an Array of objects.

So you can access the value with a callback function and make sure you get the first item in the Array response:

```
// It's array, so access the first result `res[0].dashboardID`
this.setState({ dashboardID: res[0].dashboardID }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.dashboardID)
})
```

Also the same idea you have to apply for `handleChangeDashboard` method, because of the async behavior. Please check [@Solo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53505145/4312466) for details.

*Please take a look at `setState` [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), for further details*.

Comment: can u take look at my code again, i used a callback but its still undefined, i edited it.

Comment: Would be great if you could show the code for the state and also a screenshot of the data that you get back from the fetch.

Comment: Don't nest the second then in the previous one. Just try to chain them as follow: `then(res => res.json()).then(res => {  // your custom logic, where you update the state })`

Comment: Edited it without it being nested within the second one, i also added picture of the data from the fetch. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: It's because it's array. That's the issue .

Comment: Thanks!! i love u

Comment: @bobb1213131 glad I helped you. If this answer helped you - you can accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```js
// how it is
handleChangeDashboard = (Dashboard) => {
  this.setState({ Dashboard: Dashboard.value });
  this.getDashboardID();
}

// how it should be
handleChangeDashboard = (Dashboard) => {
  this.setState({ Dashboard: Dashboard.value }, () => {
     this.getDashboardID();
  });
}
```

Why?

```
fetch(`http://ca-fpscfb2:4000/dashboardID?name=${this.state.Dashboard}`)
```

`this.state.Dashboard` could be `undefined` because `setState` is not synchronous.

Comment: You're right about the async behavior of `this.setState`, but the second issue is that the response in an Array, while he expects an object. You can check my answer for details :)

Comment: You're totally correct, I'd say your answer is currently incomplete because you need both this fix and array access for response to get it to work as expected.